# Proving Zero Covariance of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, covariance

Let $u>t>s\ge0$

I Want to know whether the following statement:

$Cov[(W_t - W_s) -\frac{t-s}{u-s} (W_u-W_s),W_k] =0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\forall K \in \{u,s\}$

implies :

$Cov[(W_t - W_s) -\frac{t-s}{u-s} (W_u-W_s),(W_u,W_s)] = 0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Math1000 This is a follow up question from my other question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209701/conditional-brownian-motion . I know I can find the conditional distribution and go from there, but I want to know if we can prove it this way

Comment: How is Cov$(X|Y)$ supposed to be defined? // Is it on purpose that the argument of Cov in your question is something like $A-B+B$?

Comment: @Did I am trying to solve for $E(W_t | W_u , W_s)$. The book I am reading proposes that this can be done using the increment trick where I should expand $W_t$ into $W_t - \frac{t-s}{u-s}(W_u-W_s)+\frac{t-s}{u-s}(W_u-W_s)$ So this is what I have done, but I get to the point where I have : $E( (W_t - W_s) - \frac{t-s}{u-s}(W_u-W_s)|W_s,W_u) + A$ where A is the correct answer according to the book. So I want to know how can i prove that I can drop the conditioning on $W_u,W_s$, and so the next logical step is to show that they are independent by showing that they have zero covariance

Comment: @Did Sorry I had made a mistake in writing out the question that carried over from when I was trying to find the expectation

Comment: Now we are left with Cov$(A,(B,C))$, still a mystery. About the question itself, why not expand everything and use repeatedly that the covariance of Brownian motion is... what you know? This will tell you whether the covariances you are interested in are zero or not.

Comment: @dimebucker91 "The book I am reading " is?

Comment: @Math1000 Its a set of lecture notes i found online. Here is the link: http://disi.unal.edu.co/~gjhernandezp/mathcomm/slides/bm.pdf , the problem is on page 11/12

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my collection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $F_{t,s}:=(W_t-W_s)-\frac{t-s}{u-s}(W_u-W_s)$. Your intention is to argue that the jointly Gaussian random variables $F_{t,s}, W_s$ and $W_u$ are such that $F_{t,s}$ is independent of $W_s, W_u$. [Being Jointly Gaussian, it is enough to show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) that $\mathbb {C}ov(F_{t,s}, W_s) = \mathbb {C}ov(F_{t,s}, W_u) = 0$.

Well,
$$
\mathbb {C}ov(F_{t,s}, W_s) = \mathbb E[F_{t,s}W_s]-\mathbb E[F_{t,s}]\mathbb E[W_s] = \Big(s-s-\frac{t-s}{u-s}(s-s)\Big) - 0\cdot0= 0
$$

and

$$
\mathbb {C}ov(F_{t,s}, W_u) = \mathbb E[F_{t,s}W_u]-\mathbb E[F_{t,s}]\mathbb E[W_u] = \Big(t-s-\frac{t-s}{u-s}(u-s)\Big) - 0\cdot0 = 0
$$

Therefore, $F_{s,t}$ is independent of $W_s, W_u$, from which we deduce $$\ \mathbb E[F_{t,s}\vert W_s, W_u] = \mathbb E[F_{t,s}] = 0\,.$$ That is,

> $$ \mathbb E[W_t - W_s\vert W_s, W_u] = \frac{t-s}{u-s}\mathbb E [W_u - W_s\vert W_s, W_u] = \frac{t-s}{u-s}(W_u - W_s)\,.$$

Comment: What is it about joint gaussians that lets us say that independence implies joint independence?

Comment: @dimebucker91, What property must the joint pdf of $F_{t,s}, W_s$ and $W_u$ satisfy to justify the independence you seek? Because we are working with a joint Gaussian pdf, do the computed covariations being $0$ imply that the joint pdf satisfies this property?